# nslookup can resolve but ping cannot

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, dns, centos

I noticed some strange behaviour when setting up a web server on a local network. when i tried typing the hostname into a browser it redirected me to a url on the internet, so naturally i tried pinging it using the hostname but it didn't work, whereas the ip is fine. I tested nslookup and the DNS entry is there.

my setup is a raspberry pi with a centos os running apache and a PC running windows 10. i am not running a domain. The centos system is the only machine on my network that i am unable to address directly, as far as i know.

When i try to ping the webserver by hostname it says Ping request could not find host and yet nslookup is able to resolve the ip no problem. Why is this?

I have tried installing a samba server and winbind on the centos machine with no luck (i can access the samba server from windows using the ip only)

i found this link describing a similar problem, however it is over a decade old and netbios is not longer supported.

I know i can add a line to the host file, however this is a bandaid solution and would like a most satisfying answer.

Any ideas?

here are some relevent config files.

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
#initgroups: files sss

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns wins

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   nisplus sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files nisplus sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

Comment: Unclear: Are you pinging using an external IP (Internet) or a local IP of `192.168.x.x`?

Comment: @harrymc local ip, sorry.

Comment: Sounds impossible. Perhaps a firewall?

Comment: @harrymc i agree, its most peculiar. I also had that thought and i disabled the firewall on the centos machine a few days ago, didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does the router have an internal firewall? Otherwise, disabling Security-Enhanced Linux (SELinux) might help.

Comment: @harrymc its not the routers firewall other machines can ping by hostname on the network, just not windows 10 ones, cant confirm for other versions of windows as I only have windows 10 available. disabled SELinux, still wont allow pings in by hostname.

Comment: Do I understand that this is a problem of Windows not pinging Linux? If you have not set up NETBIOS in Samba, Windows has no way to convert the server name to IP.

Comment: @harrymc Correct, but there is no packages in yum that add netbios. https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=netbios&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=

Comment: Installing samba to resolve name resolution problems is certainly not the way to go. You should instead post more concrete details on names you are trying to resolve... As well as real traces of the output, without any kind of re interpretation of it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I can edit the post to include the outputs of the commands you want me to run. What should I run?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Samba to participate in the Windows WORKGROUP is done by configuring the
[smb.conf file](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html).

The important parameters are (if I remember right):

```
[global]
# NetBIOS identification
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = COMPUTER-NAME
wins support = Yes
```

Samba will use NetBIOS to make itself known on the Windows network in the
default WORKGROUP and will act as a potential WINS server if one is not available.

May also be necessary:

```
encrypt passwords = true
```

I suggest to check well all parameters in `smb.conf` that may relate to NETBIOS
or WINS.

Comment: It didn't work, though interestingly `testparm` appears to be showing a different config file even though i edited the one it reports in `testparm`, even after restarting linux... i guess its using a cached version of the config file?

Comment: Caching is not a good explanation. Try to force it with `testparm /etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Comment: I did that, and it was no different, however after doing some testing i have discovered that it is using the correct file but is not showing all of the declarations. I have a second linux machine (running debian) which is able to ping as expected without any of the declarations you mentioned, except for workgroup but that doesn't appear in `testparm` either.

Comment: Try to copy smb.conf from that machine then.

Comment: i tried, didn't work.

Comment: This seems to be a local problem of how the Windows computers are set up or their connection to the network. Too many parameters are possible for me to guess.